# What does Conv2D(32, (3, 3) in TensorFlow mean?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

On the CNN image classification example from a tensor's flow tutorial page (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/cnn),

There is a code that goes like

```
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
```

I understand that the image is 32 by 32 with a channel of 3 for RGB but what does the Conv2D(32, (3, 3) represent?
Specifically the (3,3).

Comment: Probably the size of the convolution kernels? I'd suggest you to watch some short tutorial about deep learning, as you're asking a question about something fundamental

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `(3,3)` specifies the shape of the convolutional kernel. Check out the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D) for more information.

[image]

Comment: I see so, in this case, it's just expressing that there's 32 3 by 3 filters?